# Change to database done on LAN machine through web site app not reflected on localhost

Tags: crud

I made a CRUD web application in netbeans ide.

When I add an entry from another machine the change is not reflected on this machine.

I made change from 192.168.0.19:8080/appname on another computer and the change is not relected on localhost:8080/appname. Glassfish server is run on localhost.

Need to test this but maybe because I'm sending to the same port on different machines? Should I try with port 8181?

Im thinking since I autogenerated it the app wont support AJAX?

Update works if I hit return as soon as I added a record in another machine, or if I add a new record. So the solution should involve auto-refreshing the page in a time interval.

Set up primefaces and tried this in xhtml

```
<p:poll interval="10" listener="#{phonerecordController.listener}" update="@all" />
```

But I'm not sure which method should be the listener.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:poll interval="10" listener="#{phonerecordController.preparelist}" update="@all" />
```

Set up primefaces then put the above code inside xhtml and it worked.